# Delete cell if cells in column is empty or having value “Null”

Tags: excel, vba

I have this piece of code and want to repeat it 50 times or till there are no values in the cells to the right

```
Sub DeleteCellShiftLeft()  

    For i = 1000 To 1 Step -1        

        If (Cells(i, 2).Value = "") Then 

            Cells(i, 2).Delete shift:=xlToLeft

        End If     

    Next i 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if there is any more data to the right, you can use the Find function to locate the rightmost cell containing data.

Try this:

```
    ' Run the code 50 times
    For x = 0 to 50

        ' Use the Find function to locate the bottom rightmost cell with any content in it.
        Set BottomRightCell = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(what:="*", After:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

        ' If the rightmost data is in column 2 or less (where you are deleting from), then exit the loop.
        If BottomRightCell.Column <= 2 Then
            Exit For
        End If

        ' Otherwise, call your code.
        DeleteCellShiftLeft()

    Next x
```

This should call your code 50 times, or stop calling it if there is no more data in cells to the right.

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: I rearranged some of my data as well and it works just fine with your code Thanks a lot!

Comment: @wannaknow2017 glad to hear it was useful!